# Checking if a linear transformation has an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let: $f, g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$
We have a linear transformation:
$$T(f):\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$$
$$T(f) = xf(x)$$ 
We are to check if transformation $T(f)$ has an inverse transformation.
I started with a postulate that
$$T^{-1}(g) = \frac{1}{x}g(x)$$
It is easy to check if $T^{-1}$ is a linear transformation.
However I am really not sure if it's a proper one, because it's not a map:
$$\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$$
is it?
Of course $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a space of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, what you call $T^{-1}$ is not defined for constants: the result would be $a/x$, which is not a polynomial.

Comment: Note that $T$ is one-to-one (injective), but not onto (surjective).

Comment: Thank you! So $T$ has no inverse?